# Creating an INSERT-OUTPUT-INSERT query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have an Access front end pushing queries to an SQL Server Express 2012 back-end.  I have a 1-to-1 relationship between two tables and need to insert a record into each (using unbound form).  In access I could create a view with both tables and the record would be made automatically where the PK of the first would be used as the FK in the next.  SQL is different.  Im trying to use an OUTPUT argument but don't understand the syntax.  This is what I have:

```
INSERT into tblInsp (clmInsDate, clmDistrictNumber, clmBandColor)
VALUES ('1-1-15',4,6)
OUTPUT INSERTED.InspectionKEY AS myVar ;somehow get the value
INTO xtblInspRef (clmInsp, clmRefNumber, clmInspType)
VALUES (myVar,231,3)    ;use the identity as foreign key
```

I am new to SQL but learning on-the-fly. Here is an image of the relationship:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDFD9.jpg)

Comment: Is the `tblInsp.InspectionKEY` column an `INT IDENTITY(n,n)` column? If so you can use the system function `@@IDENTITY`. See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: Don't use @@IDENTITY. If you have a trigger that does an insert you will get that value instead of the one you want. You should instead use SCOPE_IDENTITY.

Comment: Of course since this is a single row insert you can just use INSERTED.InspectionKey https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: So would this work? 

    INSERT into tblInsp (clmInsDate, clmDistrictNumber, clmBandColor)
    VALUES ('1-1-15',4,6) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.InspectionKey INSERT INTO xtblInspRef (clmInsp, clmRefNumber, clmInspType) 
    VALUES (INSERTED.InspectionKey,231,3)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do what I wanted using a temp table:

```
DECLARE @scratch AS TABLE(InspectionKey int, clmRefNumber int, clmInspType int) 

INSERT INTO tblInsp (clmInsDate, clmBandColor, clmDistrictNumbr, clmCalibrationBlock, clmTGauge, clmHarTester,clmInspecter) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.InspectionKey, 231, 3 
    INTO @scratch 
VALUES ('1-1-15',4,6) 
INSERT INTO xtblInspRef (clmInsp, clmRefNumber, clmInspType) 
SELECT InspectionKey, clmrefnumber,clmInspType 
FROM @scratch
```

Comment: Took me a while looking at a lot of examples and lots of testing.  The msdn site was way too arbritrary for me to be able to read yet